# How to fetch data just on the first load of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

I want to know how to fetch data just on the first load of component and not on every reload.
I hope that is making sense.
so something like that will be calling in every load

```
useEffect(() => getData(), []);
```

For example : I want to fetch the data for the pieces when the user click on pieces section not before. see the picture.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJACX.png)

Comment: You could check if the data is already there with an `if` statement. If there is no data, you call `getData()`

Comment: yeah, thanks that is true, but if a query return 0 records.

Comment: That useEffect with an empty array of dependencies should be ok to only call it once: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect

Comment: this looks like fine , the empty dependency array makes sure  to execute code within the useEffect only one time